# Error al intentar cargar las opciones de un select con ng-repat

Tags: html, angularjs

Resulta que tengo este objeto

```
[{"id":"1","descripcion":"TRIBUNAL ITINERANTE","id_usuario":"1","fecha_de_registro":"2017-04-05 15:57:17"},{"id":"9","descripcion":"TRIBUNAL 2","id_usuario":"0","fecha_de_registro":"2017-04-05 17:14:47"},{"id":"10","descripcion":"TRIBUNAL3","id_usuario":"0","fecha_de_registro":"2017-04-05 17:14:56"}]
```

y necesito cargar estas opciones a un select, lo hago de este modo pero no sucede nada :(

```
<div class="input-field col s12 m12 l6">
          <select>
              <option ng-repeat="x in tipo_de_tribunal" value="{{x.id}}">{{x.descripcion}}</option>
          </select>

          <label>Tribunal</label>
</div>
```

con esta funcion cargo la data

```
$scope.openModal = function(div,button) {

        // Asigno el nombre de la accion seleccionada (registrar o modificar)
        $rootScope.button = button;

        // CargarForeignKey

        $rootScope.get('api/tipo_de_tribunal').then(function(response) {
            $scope.tipo_de_tribunal = response;
        });

        // Hacer esto si la accion seleccionada es registrar
        if(button == "registrar") {
            // Desmarca cualquier elemento en la datatable
            $scope.table.rows().deselect();
            // Abre la ventana modal
            $(div).modal('open');   

        }

        // Hacer esto si la accion seleccionada es modificar
        if(button == "modificar") {
            // Si la cantidad de filas seleccionadas es mayor que 1
            if($scope.table.rows('.selected').data().length > 1) {
                $rootScope.alert("Error", "Solo puedes modificar un fila a la vez", "warning");
            // Si la cantidad de filas seleccionada es ninguna
            } else if ($scope.table.rows('.selected').data().length <= 0) {
                $rootScope.alert("Error", "Debes seleccionar un registro a modificar", "warning");
            // Si la cantidad de filas seleccionada es solo 1 (Solo se puede modificar una fila a la vez)
            } else {
                $(div).modal('open');


                $rootScope.get('api/' + $scope.obj_padre + '/' + $scope.clave_primaria).then(function(response) {
                    $scope.datos = response[0];
                }, function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                });


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hola, podrías agregar el código de controlador?

Comment: Qué error muestra ?

Comment: no muestra ningun error, simplemente deja el `select` en blanco

Comment: con esta funcion cargo la data

Answer (score 0):

Ya solucione mi problema, al parecer no hay ningun error. Estoy usando Materialize y al parecer existe un choque con la clase y ng-repeat o ng-options de angular.

Lo solucione de esta manera

```
<select class="browser-default" ng-options="item as item.descripcion for item in tipo_de_tribunal track by item.id" ng-model="selected"></select>
```

No estoy conforme puesto que yo queria usar la clase de materialize select, pero bueno, veo que ese es el error